# Word files downloaded using AWS S3 pre-signed url opens in "Protected view" mode

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, docx, pre-signed-url

I have a files (docx) in the s3 bucket. 
I am downloading it using the S3 pre-signed url. It is getting downloaded.
But when i download and open the file it is getting opened in "Protected View" mode.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue or give me any hint what can I do to open this docx file in normal read only mode?

Comment: Did you try save as in another location? or did your try some play with `info`  in word file menu?

Comment: i have tried to play with info in word file menu. But I don't think file menu has something related to this. because when I download the same file from onprem it is getting downloaded normally. But when I download it from S3 bucket and open the docx file it is getting opened in Protected view. Can you suggest mein some setting on the S3 bucket related to this issue.